# Simple page spider in Python - SQLite won't update

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web-crawler

I have a very simple page spider that crawls for words on a given page and stores the count of the words in a SQLite data base. Although, the code exits with the `exit code 0`, the database won't update with any entries.

I don't know if I'm just snow blind or there's something inherently wrong with my code.

Here's the structure of the project and the code:

- spider.py
- input.txt
- words.db

  - utilities (folder):
  - url_utilities.py
  - database_utilities.py

**spider.py**

```
import argparse
from utilities import url_utilities, database_utilities


def main(database: str, url_list_file: str):
    big_word_list = []
    urls = url_utilities.load_urls_from_file(url_list_file)
    for url in urls:
        print(f"Reading {url}")
        page_content = url_utilities.load_page(url=url)
        words = url_utilities.scrape_page(page_contents=page_content)
        big_word_list.extend(words)

    # database code
    path = "C:\\Users\\baduker\\PycharmProjects\\page_spider\\words.db"
    database_utilities.create_database(database_path=path)
    database_utilities.save_words_to_database(database_path=path, words_list=big_word_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-db", "--database", help="SQLite File Name")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="File with urls")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    database_file = args.database
    input_file = args.input

    main(database=database_file, url_list_file=input_file)
```

**url_utilities.py**

```
import re
import string
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def load_urls_from_file(file_path: str):
    try:
        with open("input.txt") as f:
            content = f.readlines()
            return content
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"The file {file_path} could not be found.")
        exit(2)


def load_page(url: str):
    response = urlopen(url)
    html = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return html


def scrape_page(page_contents: str):
    chicken_noodle = BeautifulSoup(page_contents, "html.parser")

    for script in chicken_noodle(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()

    text = chicken_noodle.get_text()
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))

    text = ' '.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    plain_text = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, text))

    clean_words = []
    words = plain_text.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        clean = True
        for punctuation_marks in string.punctuation:
            if punctuation_marks in word:
                clean = False
            if any(char.isdigit() for char in word):
                clean = False
                # at least two characters but no more than 10
            if len(word) < 2 or len(word) > 10:
                clean = False
            if not re.match(r'^\w+$', word):
                clean = False
            if clean:
                try:
                    clean_words.append(word.lower())
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    print(".")
    return clean_words
```

**database_utilities.py**

```
import sqlite3 as lite


def create_database(database_path: str):
    conn = lite.connect(database_path)
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("drop table if exists words")
        ddl = "create table words (word text not null primary key, usage_count int default 1 not null);"
        cur.execute(ddl)
        ddl = "create unique index words_word_uindex on words (word);"
        cur.execute(ddl)
    conn.close()


def save_words_to_database(database_path: str, words_list: list):
    conn = lite.connect(database_path)
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        for word in words_list:
            sql = "select count(word) from words where word='" + word + "';"
            cur.execute(sql)
            count = cur.fetchone()[0]
            if count > 0:
                sql = "update words set usage_count = usage_count + 1 where word='" + word + "';"
            else:
                sql = "insert into words(word) values ('" + word + "');"
            cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print(f"Database save complete!")
```

**input.txt**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working.

I suspect you have permissions issue with the database file.
Make sure this line points to a folder where you have permissions to write:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\baduker\\PycharmProjects\\page_spider\\words.db"
```

or just remove the path and see if it works.

```
path = "words.db"
```

Comment: You got me going in the right direction. It turned out I did have some file permission issues. All fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ur context manager i.e. with

> with con:

Hope u should commit before closing it. I mean u should commit in that with block itself.
U should do that in your database utility file.